# How can I track executables created by my user on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, monitoring

Using Linux, I would like to track the executables that are executed in my name, including the whole command line (in practice, every exec*() done as my own user). A program I do not control is supposed, in order to handle a task, to execute the program I pass in, but I want make sure it does so, and what options it uses. The program I don't control is sneaky, and seems to change behavior depending on the name of the program it is supposed to execute for the task, so I can't pass in a shell script that would log the info and invoke the real program.

Is it possible for me to be informed of all exec*()s done as my user on the system on Linux, including full command line? Short of running `ps` in a loop, that is. I'd rather do it directly on the system on which I work and not require root access, but if need be I can spawn a system on which I have root access, install the programs and investigate there.

Using Ubuntu 12.4 LTS.

Comment: I'm asking here rather than Ask Ubuntu, as it is more a Unix/Linux question than a real Ubuntu question.

Comment: How sneaky is the program? Does it try to detect or bypass debuggers? Is it dynamically linked? If it's too sneaky, you may need to use a virtual machine where you're root. (This may be the simplest strategy even for a program that isn't particularly sneaky.)

Comment: @Gilles That is indeed a possibility, I'm going to try a VM, then update the question if that turns out to be workable.

Comment: Note: you appear to actually want the programname and arguments, which the answer with `audit` gives, but a 'whole command line' in shell could also affect the child process using redirection/piping and envvar settings as well as containing substitutions/expansions, nonsignificant quoting and spacing, and control structures like `doa && dob`, and you won't get those.

Answer (score 11):

You need to configure `auditd` to record `execve` events. Example on RHEL5:

```
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# auditctl -a always,entry -S execve
WARNING - 32/64 bit syscall mismatch, you should specify an arch
[root@ditirlns01 ~]#
```

I ignore the arch warning and it doesn't seem to matter but you can use `-F arch=b64` or `-F arch=b32` to set it if you want.

The result of the above is:

```
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# ls /tmp/whatever
ls: /tmp/whatever: No such file or directory
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# grep whatever /var/log/audit/audit.log
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1386797915.232:5527206): argc=3 a0="ls" a1="--color=tty" a2="/tmp/whatever"
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1386797927.133:5527241): argc=3 a0="grep" a1="whatever" a2="/var/log/audit/audit.log"
[root@ditirlns01 ~]#
```

That's obviously quick and dirty but that's the basics of how you do it. What you need to do exactly probably depends heavily on what you're trying to do exactly. You can reduce audit flow using various filters in the `auditctl` command but I don't know any of that information so I don't know what to include. If you need something more specific, I'd suggest you either check the man page or post a comment to this answer and I'll update it some more.

Hope that helps push you in the right direction.

**EDIT:**

Since your question involves looking at a particular user I can show you that:

```
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# auditctl -a always,entry -S execve -F euid=16777216
WARNING - 32/64 bit syscall mismatch, you should specify an arch
```

Identical to the above, but only `execve`'s by someone running with the effective user ID of `16777216` will get logged. If you need to specify the user's `loginuid` value (who they initially logged into the system as) then you filter by `auid` instead:

```
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# auditctl -a always,entry -S execve -F auid=16777216
WARNING - 32/64 bit syscall mismatch, you should specify an arch
```

AUID/loginuid filters would be useful for example if the user will do a `su` or `sudo` to root. In that situation there will be a lot of stuff running as root, but you're only concerned with the stuff that got kicked off by the user in question. `auditctl` also lets you stack filters so you can filter by both `euid` and `auid`:

```
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# auditctl -a always,entry -S execve -F auid=16777216 -F euid=0
WARNING - 32/64 bit syscall mismatch, you should specify an arch
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# ls /tmp/nashly -ltar
ls: /tmp/nashly: No such file or directory
[root@ditirlns01 ~]# grep nashly /var/log/audit/audit.log
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1386798635.199:5529285): argc=4 a0="ls" a1="--color=tty" a2="/tmp/nashly" a3="-ltar"
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1386798646.048:5529286): argc=3 a0="grep" a1="nashly" a2="/var/log/audit/audit.log"
```

Comment: “Note that I do not have root access”. (Otherwise this would be a good answer.)

Comment: Damn...so close...

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I should add that I had to install auditctl by apt-get, it wasn't preinstalled on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Nice examples. But are there any way to get the exit code out of the audit log?

Answer (score 0):

You have asked something simple.  I have made an example with `mplayer` but I guess it can be adapted to other situations :

```
#! /bin/sh
# This executable must be used instead of /usr/bin/mplayer
# do not forget the chmod +x filename...
LOG=/tmp/mplayer.log
echo "$@" >> $LOG
if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -f "$1" ] ; then
        filename="$1"
        echo "$(date "+%F %T") $(basename "$filename")" \
        | tee -a "$(dirname "$filename")/mplayer.log"  >> $LOG
fi
/usr/bin/mplayer "$@"
```

As you can see this is very simple : It parse the first argument, as it is a file, a log is made into the central file `$LOG` and concatenated into a file (which have always the same name `mplayer.log` in the same directory.

So, user may get the latest film he has read on each directories.

Comment: The Q specifically said that substituting a script wouldn't work.

Comment: Possible, but this fits beter for my situation : I have no problem of security and I may choose the script I run.  As incredible as it could seems, I have though of this simplest simplest solution, maybe someone else will be interested not in going into geek-only stuffs.  I admit the previous solution is more secure!